# Возвращение данных с базы данных

Tags: mysql, node.js

Есть файл Controlller

```html
export let a = ''
import * as mysqldb from './mysql/connectsql.js'
const MySqls = new mysqldb.conndb()
export class Conrole {
    async login(req, res) {
        try {
            console.log(await MySqls.zapros('SELECT * FROM `user`;'))
            return res.status(200).json({mes: "USSS"})
        } catch(e) {
            return res.status(500).json(e)
        }  
    }
}
```

Который обращается к файлу connectsql для получения информации с базы данных

```js
import mysql from 'mysql'
export class conndb {
  async zapros(zaprosname){
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'server131.hosting.reg.ru',
      port: '3306',
      user     : '',
      password : '',
      database : ''
    });
    connection.connect(err => {
      if (err != null) {console.log(err)}
    });
    let query = 'SELECT * FROM `user`;'
    connection.query(zaprosname, (error, results, fields) => {
      console.log(results)
      return results
    });

    connection.end();
  }
}
```

как вернуть поле result после обращения к бд в файл Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте либо через коллбэк функцию

```
export class Conrole {
    async login(req, res) {
        try {
            console.log(await MySqls.zapros('SELECT * FROM `user`;', (res) => {
                return res.status(200).json({mes: "USSS"})
            }
            ))
            
        } catch(e) {
            return res.status(500).json(e)
        }  
    }
}

import mysql from 'mysql'
export class conndb {
  async zapros(zaprosname, callBack) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'server131.hosting.reg.ru',
      port: '3306',
      user     : '',
      password : '',
      database : ''
    });
    connection.connect(err => {
      if (err != null) {console.log(err)}
    });
    let query = 'SELECT * FROM `user`;';
    connection.query(zaprosname, (error, results, fields) => {
      console.log(results)
      callBack(results);
    });
    connection.end();
  }
}
```

Либо с использованием Promice

```
export class conndb {
  async zapros(zaprosname){
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'server131.hosting.reg.ru',
      port: '3306',
      user     : '',
      password : '',
      database : ''
    });
    connection.connect(err => {
      if (err != null) {console.log(err)}
    });
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(zaprosname, (error, results, fields) => {
          console.log(results)
          if (results) {
              resolve(results);
          } else {
              reject(error)
          }
          
          connection.end();
        });
    })
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Пробовал, не работает возвращает undefined

Comment: @Pfjksla Поставьте перед `return result` `console.log('возврат')` и посмотрите, что появится быстрее в консоли, возврат или значение из `console.log(results)`? Кстати, `console.log(results)` выводит ведь данные а не undefined? И вы **await** добавили перед фукнцией?

Comment: Сначала появляется вывод, потом undefined и только потом console.log(result)(как раз то что надо) который находится в функции connection.query, да, await стоит, но VS code считает что await ни на что не влияет

Comment: @Pfjksla Изменил ответ, попробуйте. Либо через функцию обратного вызова, либо через промисы. Промисы мне кажутся красивее.

Comment: Ни то не другое не работает, через промисы просто ничего не возвращает, а через колбэк функцию возникает ошибка https://imgur.com/a/4PyIMmX

Comment: Промис не может ничего не возвращать... что вам выдаёт console в `console.log(await MySqls.zapros('SELECT * FROM `user`;'))`?

Comment: Ничего не выдаёт

Comment: Я ошибся в написании промиса, должно быть **Promise**.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь, заработало как надо.